# 2D dynamic array uninitialized - argument to function C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, 2d, arguments

i have a question for you!

I have a C program in which i have a dynamic 2d array in my main function:

```
int **neighbours;
```

which i initialize based on args from command line.
The problem is that i want to clean up the code a bit. To do that i want to create a function in a header file that takes the array uninitialized as a reference argument and initialize it there.

This is how i call the function:

```
init(&nodeNum, &neighbours, argv[1], &nodes);
```

this is how i declare the function in the header file:

```
int init(int *nodeNum, int ***neighbours, char *arg, struct node **nodes)
```

and this is how try to allocate the memory:

```
neighbours=malloc(*nodeNum*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0;i<*nodeNum;i++){
            neighbours[i] = malloc(*nodeNum*sizeof(int *));
        }
```

well obviously something doesn't go well and it crashes! any hints on what i may be doing wrong?

thanks to the help of some nice people the malloc now works, but filling the nodes failes!

here is the whole code of the function:

```
int init(int *nodeNum, int ***neighbours, char *arg, struct node **nodes){
FILE *file;
char buffer[4];
int i,y,distance;

if(strcmp(arg,"-l")==0){
        file = fopen("C:\\Users\\trendkiller\\thesis\\matrix.txt","r");
        printf("parsing adjacency matrix from file\n\n");
        //file = fopen ("C:\\Users\\trendkiller\\thesis\\matrix.txt", "r" ) ;
        *nodeNum = atoi(fgets(buffer,4,file));
        *neighbours=malloc(*nodeNum*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0;i<*nodeNum;i++){
            (*neighbours)[i] = malloc(*nodeNum*sizeof(int *));
        }
        printf("this prints\n");
        printf("number of nodes: %s", buffer);
        for(i=0;i<*nodeNum;i++){
            for(y=0;y<*nodeNum;y++){
                fgets(buffer,4,file);
                (*neighbours)[i][y]=atoi(buffer);
                            }
        }


    }
    else{
        *nodeNum = atoi(arg);

        *neighbours=malloc(*nodeNum*sizeof(int *));
        printf("this prints\n");
        for(i=0;i<*nodeNum;i++){
            (*neighbours)[i] = malloc(*nodeNum*sizeof(int *));
        }

        *nodes=malloc(*nodeNum*sizeof(struct node));

        for(i=0;i<30;i++){
            (*nodes)[i].x=rand()%100;
            (*nodes)[i].y=rand()%100;
        }
        printf("this prints\n");

        printf("creating new adjacency matrix\n\n");
        for(i=0; i<*nodeNum; i++){
            for(y=0; y<*nodeNum; y++){
                distance=sqrt((((*nodes)[y].x-(*nodes)[i].x)*((*nodes)[y].x-(*nodes)[i].x))+(((*nodes)[y].y-(*nodes)[i].y)*((*nodes)[y].y-(*nodes)[i].y)));
                if(i==y){
                    (*neighbours)[i][y]=-1;
                }
                else if(distance<=20){
                    (*neighbours)[i][y]=1;
                }
                else {
                    (*neighbours)[i][y]=0;
                }
            }

        }

        file = fopen("C:\\Users\\trendkiller\\thesis\\matrix.txt","a+");
        fprintf(file,"%d\n",*nodeNum);
        for(i=0;i<*nodeNum;i++){
            for(y=0;y<*nodeNum;y++){
                fprintf(file,"%d\n", (*neighbours)[i][y]);
            }
        }
    }
```

return 0;

}

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You have a pointer to pointer, not an 2D array. You might use this as an emulation for that, but why not just use dynamic 2D arrays as they come in C since C99. Also what the purpose of your `arg` and `nodes` are is not clear.

Comment: i am not sure what you mean "just use dynamic 2D arrays" i thought that is what i am doing! (just not successfully..) the arg param is the first argument from the command line, which is a number or a string. if it is a number i create that many nodes in the "struct node *nodes" else if it is a string i parse an adjacency matrix (neighbours) from a file which again also fills the "struct node *nodes" array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `neighbours` is passed by value, so modifications to it inside the function have no effect. You need to pass it by pointer, and modify it indirectly:

```
int init(int *nodeNum, int ***neighbours_ptr, char *arg, struct node *nodes) {
    *neighbours_ptr = malloc(*nodeNum*sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0;i<*nodeNum;i++){
        (*neighbours_ptr)[i] = malloc(*nodeNum*sizeof(int *));
    }
}
```

You also need to pass `&neighbours` instead of `neighbours` as the second argument of `init`.

Comment: thanks, it does make sense this way! but still it doesn't run!

Comment: @tk66 Could you please elaborate on the "does not run" part? Does it crash? What do you see in the debugger? By the way, why do you pass it a pointer to `nodeNum` rather than `nodeNum`, and why do you pass `nodes` at all?

Comment: it wasn't allocating the memory correctly but now it does! but now it crashes when i try to fill the node array. I pass it as an argument because i need to malloc this as well and use it from the main function later. nodeNum is also somehting i have to use later in the main function and it gets it's value in the init function when parsing the arguments or a file.

Comment: @tk66 If you need to malloc nodes as well, you should pass it by pointer to pointer, too.

Comment: isn't this what i am now doing? i updated the code ! (i haven't coded in C for some time now, so sorry if i am doing stupid things! java ruined me!)

Comment: @tk66 Oh, now you do pass it by pointer! I did not notice the edit before.

Comment: it works now! thanks for your help! and everyone who helped:)

Answer (score 0):

In the example code you give one error is here:

```
neighbours[i] = malloc(*nodeNum*sizeof(int *));
```

where it should be

```
neighbours[i] = malloc(*nodeNum*sizeof(int));
```

Why do you use an emulation of a 2D array instead of a real one? This works since C99:

```
int (*neighbours)[nodeNum] = malloc(sizeof(int[nodeNum][nodeNum]));
```

You would not have a need of an `init` such as yours that just allocates memory.

Why to you pass a pointer to `nodeNum` and not the value directly? If you still need an `init` function that does some initialization and not just allocation. The interface would look something like

```
void init(size_t nodeNum, int neighbours[nodeNum][nodeNum]);
```

Comment: i need the init function because it does other stuff as well.. and i need the nodeNum as a pointer because it depends on the argument of the args, which is parsed in the init.

i will edit my post to include the whole code of the function init! thanks for your time!